Is there a way of finding a closed-form expression for $\int_0^\infty\frac{k^2J_0(k)^2\,\mathrm{d}k}{k^4+\left( k^2+x^2 \right)^2}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$?
I am trying to find a closed-form expression for the following improper integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{k^2 J_0(k)^2 \, \mathrm{d}k}{k^4 + \left( k^2 + x^2 \right)^2} \, , 
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
This integral arises when solving a fluid mechanics problem.

I am considering using the method of residues in the upper half-plane with the standard contour of integration in the complex plane.
Apparently, the integral on the contour $\mathcal{C}_R$ representing a semi-circular arc of radius $R$ does NOT vanish as $R \to \infty$.
The four simple poles are located at $$\pm \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{-2 + 2i}\,\,\, \mbox{and}\,\, \pm \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{-2 - 2i}
$$
The poles with positive imaginary parts are $$z_1 = \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{-2 + 2i}\,\,\, \mbox{and}\,\, z_2 = - \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{-2 - 2i}
$$

The integral is therefore:
$$
i\pi \Big( \text{Res}\{ f(z), z_1 \} + \text{Res}\{ f(z), z_2 \} \Big)
-\frac{1}{2} \int_{ \mathcal{C}_R } f(z) \, \mathrm{d} z
 \, .
$$
Any hint on how to obtain the contour integral over $\mathcal{C}_R$ ?.

The asymptotic of $J_0$ holds for arguments which are less than $\pi$, I doubt that the integral along the semicircle is zero

@AdityaDwivedi For large argument, the Bessel functions $J_n(x)$ for all integer orders go to zero as $J_0(x)=O(x^{-1/2})$. See the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17#E3

@AdityaDwivedi You're right. The integral over the semi-circle is not zero. Thanks for the hint!

@Bunneh You're right. The integral over the semi-circle is not zero. Thanks for the hint!

The integral over the semicircle would be zero if the function were $$\frac{k^{2}J_{0}(k)^2 e^{iax}}{k^4+(k^2+x^2)^{2}}, \quad a \ge 2. $$

@RandomVariable I think is is given as a series expansion in terms of $x^2$ but I cannot figure out the general term of the series

For what it's worth, the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{kJ_{0}(k)^{2}}{k^{4}+(k^{2}+x^{2})^{2}} , \mathrm dk $ is $1/2$ times $2 \pi i $ times the sum of the residues of $\frac{kJ_{0}(k)H_{0}^{(1)}(k)}{k^{4}+(k^{2}+x^{2})^{2}} $in the upper half-plane.  And the value of  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{k^{2}J_{0}(k) Y_{0}(k)}{k^{4}+(k^{2}+x^{2})^{2}} , \mathrm dk $  is $1/2$ times $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $\frac{k^{2} J_{0}(k)H_{0}^{(1)}(k)}{k^{4}+(k^{2}+x^{2})^{2}} $ in the upper half-plane.

In my first comment it should be $e^{iak}$.

@RandomVariable for the integral of interest, $H_0^{(2)}$ should be involved here because the function is even. If the function were odd, that would be of $H_0^{(1)}$.

If we  integrate $\frac{z^{2} J_{0}(z)H_{0}^{(2)}(z)}{z^{4}+(z^{2}+x^{2})^{2}} $ on the complex plane, we would need to integrate in the lower half-plane if we want the integral over the semicircle to vanish. But on the lower side of the branch cut, $H_{0}^{(2)}(-k) = -J_{0}(k)- i Y_{0}(k), \ k >0.$  So this doesn't give us the value of the integral you're asking about.

The following is a supplement to Claude Leibovici's answer.
Let $\phi_{k}= \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} $ and $\phi_{k_{1}, k_{2}, \ldots , k_{r}} = \prod _{j=1}^{r} \frac{(-1)^{k_{j}}}{(k_{j})!}$
I will use the method of brackets to show that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{J_{0}(k){}^2}{k^2\color{red}{+}c} \, \mathrm dk =\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{c}}  \, I_{0}\left(\sqrt{c}\right)^2-\frac 4 \pi \,_2F_3\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};c\right), \quad (c \in \mathbb{C}, \  c \not \le  0). $$
Then to get integral $I$ in Claude Leibovici's answer, just replace $c$ with $-c$.
The method of brackets is a generalization of Ramanujan's master theorem.
It associates a so-called "bracket series" with the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \phi_{n} \, a_{n} \, x^{\alpha n +\beta-1} \, \mathrm dx$, and the evaluation of the bracket (or brackets) series involves where the bracket (or brackets) vanishes.
You can read about the method and see worked examples in the following papers by Ivan Gonzalez, Victor Moll, and others:
Definite Integrals by the Method of Brackets. Part 1
The Method of Brackets. Part 2: Examples and Applications
Evaluation of Entries in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik Employing the Method of Brackets

The square of the Bessel function of first kind of order zero has the Maclaurin series expansion $$J_{0}(x)^{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2} )}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, x^{2k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k} \, \frac{\Gamma ( k+\tfrac{1}{2}) }{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, x^{2k}. $$
Therefore, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{0}(x)^{2}}{x^{2}+c} \, \mathrm dx  &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{0}(x)^{2} e^{-t(x^{2}+c)} \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} x^{2k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \phi_{m}  (tx^{2})^{m} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \phi_{n}(tc)^{n} \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k,m,n} \, \frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, c^{n} t^{m+n} x^{2k+2m}, \end{align} $$ which has the associated brackets series
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k,m,n} \, \frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, c^{n} \langle m+n+1\rangle \langle 2k+2m+1\rangle .$$
(In some cases you will get the correct result even if you use a Maclaurin series that doesn't have an infinite radius of convergence, but I'm not completely sure when it's permissible.)
The matrix equation corresponding to the vanishing of the brackets is $$ \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} k \\ m \\ n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
We have several cases to look at since it's an undetermined system of equations.

If we let $k$ be a free parameter, then the brackets vanish when $m=-k - \frac{1}{2}$ and $n=k-\frac{1}{2},$ and we have the contribution $$ \begin{align} S_{1} &= \frac{1}{\left|\det \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
     2 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\right|}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k} \, \frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, c^{k-1/2} \, \Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi c}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k} \, \frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, c^{k} \pi \sec (\pi k) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{\pi c}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \frac{\Gamma (k+\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)^{2}} \, c^{k} \\ &=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \, J_{0}(i \sqrt{c})^{2} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \, I_{0}(\sqrt{c})^{2}. \end{align}  $$

If we let $m$ be a free parameter, then the brackets vanish when $k=-m-\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=-m-1$, and we have the contribution
$$S_{2} = \frac{1}{\left|\det \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
     2 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\right|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{m} \,  \frac{\color{red}{\Gamma (-m)}}{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}-m)^{2}} \, c^{-m-1} \, \Gamma \left(m+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(m+1\right). $$
Since the terms of the series are not finite, we discard it.  (It's still a bit unclear to me what to with a series that diverges but has an analytic continuation.)

And if we let $n$ be a free parameter, then the brackets vanish when $k= n+ \frac{1}{2}$ and $m=-n-1$, and we have the contribution
$$ \begin{align} S_{3} &= \frac{1}{\left|\det \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
     2 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\right|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{n} \,  \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{3}{2})^{2}} \, c^{n} \, \Gamma \left(-n-\frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(n+1\right) \\ &= - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{n} \,  \frac{\Gamma (n+1)^{2}}{\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{3}{2})^{2}} \, c^{n} \, \frac{\pi \csc (\pi(n+ \tfrac{1}{2}))}{\Gamma (n+ \tfrac{3}{2})}  \\ &= - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 } \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \,  \frac{\Gamma (n+1)^{2}}{\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{3}{2})^{3}} \, c^{n} \\ &= - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \Gamma (\tfrac{3}{2})^{3}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \,  \frac{\Gamma (n+1)^{2}}{\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{3}{2})^{3}} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{3} \, c^{n} \\ &= - \frac{4}{\pi} \, _2F_{3} \left(1,1; \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; c \right). \end{align}$$
On the second line I used the reflection formula for the gamma function.

Since the Maclaurin series for $I_{0}(\sqrt{c})^{2}$ and $_2F_{3} \left(1,1; \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; \frac{3}{2}; c \right)$ converge in the same region (i.e., the whole complex plane), we add $S_{1}$ and $S_{3}$ to get $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{0}(k)^{2}}{k^{2}+c} \, \mathrm dk = S_{1} + S_{3} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \, I_{0}(\sqrt{c})^{2} - \frac{4}{\pi} \, _2F_{3} \left(1,1; \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; c \right). $$

Very nice proof. Thanks a lot.

Without complex analysis.
If you start with
$$\frac{k^2}{k^4+\left(k^2+x^2\right)^2}=\frac 1{a-b}   \left(\frac{a}{k^2-a}-\frac{b}{k^2-b}\right)$$ where
$$a=-\frac {1+i}2 x^2\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=-\frac {1-i}2 x^2$$
According to Mathematica, if $c$ is a complex
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(k){}^2}{k^2-c}\,dk$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}   \sqrt{-\frac{1}{c}}\, J_0\left(\sqrt{c}\right){}^2-\frac 4 \pi \,\,
   _2F_3\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2};-c\right)$$
This makes your integral a nice function of $x$.
If $x$ is small (say $x<2$), a good approximation is
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{k^2J_0(k)^2}{k^4+\left( k^2+x^2 \right)^2}\, dk=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \alpha_n\, x^n$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}
   ,\frac{2}{\pi },\frac{\pi}{8} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}   ,\frac{16}{27 \pi
   },\frac{3\pi \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}{256}
   ,\frac{128}{3375 \pi },\cdots\right\}$$

Thanks Claude. That was very helpful yet I am more inclined toward an exact solution potentially using the residue thm.

@keynes. Last time I used complex analysis and/or the residue theorem is probably $65^+$ years ago. But I had fun with the problem and I thank you for that. Cheers :-)

@keynes. The solution is exact

Thanks. I think the first eqn should be $\frac{1}{2(a+b)} \left(
\frac{a}{k^2-b} + \frac{b}{k^2-a} \right)$

@keynes. I do not this so but we may disagree

You're right. Both are correct. But I am 100 % certain that you forgot a factor pf 2 in front of $a-b$ in the denominator. It is indeed a nice solution.

@ClaudeLeibovici. I checked the decomposition in the first line with Mathematica, and I think it should be
$$\frac{k^2}{k^4+\left(k^2+x^2\right)^2}=\frac 1{\color{red}{2}(a-b)}   \left(\frac{a}{k^2-a}-\frac{b}{k^2-b}\right)$$
as noted in the comment above. This probably doesn't affect the rest of the post though. (+1)
